# In ASP.NET, how do I change the visibility of a button in the same column of a gridview itemtemplate when the other button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have the following gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridOpenMECs" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShow" runat="server" ImageUrl="xxx.png"
                OnClick="btnShow_OnClick" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnHidden" runat="server"
                ImageUrl="yyy.png" Visible="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

When button1's onclick serverside event is fired I want to obtain a handle on button2 so that I may change its Visible attribute to True.

```
Protected Sub btnShow_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim btn as ImageButton = CTYPE(sender, ImageButton) 'get the sending button handle
    '' what next to make btnHidden visible?
End Sub
```

How can I accomplish this?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting this line  inside onclick even                          
   " gridOpenMECs.Columns[1].Visible = true "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, C# speak ...

```
GridViewRow whichrow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
ImageButton btnHidden = (ImageButton)whichrow.FindControl("btnHidden")
```